# AWS Greengrass. Can't trigger core's lambda function from device mqtt client in local network

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

What I want to have is to send some metrics from `greengrass device` to `greengrass lambda function` in the `local network`.

I'm using the subscribe mode of [basicDiscovery.py](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/blob/master/samples/greengrass/basicDiscovery.py) to send some device metrics to the amazon greengrass core device and invoke the lambda function deployed on the core. The lambda function simply prints the event.
My confusion is when I use a subscription from `IoT Cloud -> lambda function` it work's fine but It's not working when I configure a subscription from `device -> lambda function`.
Also when I disconnect the device the device from the internet (in case 1), it buffers the messages and sends them when it gets connected to the internet again. 
I know that I'm passing `xxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` as the endpoint and it's accessible over the internet, but not sure how to have an endpoint for the core.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried sending data from device to lambda and lambda to cloud.As per my understanding you have to take care of the following points:
1.The device that is connected to greengrass should be publishing data for a topic
2.For the same topic subscription has to created between device and lambda
3.To test this behavior,create another subscription between lambda and cloud

Reference:https://medium.com/tensoriot/aws-greengrass-on-raspberry-pi-creating-core-and-node-devices-707a38452293

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I tried to trigger a lambda function in Greengrass. If I created a subscription whose source was cloud and target was lambda. Then when I published a message to a topic with my device credentials, the lambda function was triggered.

But if the connection between greengrass and AWS was lost, the lambda function didn't trigger. I needed the lambda function to work even when greengrass didn't have connection with AWS.

So I think this issue can be fixed if I change the source of subscription to device.

However, if I create a subscription with source set as device itself, then publishing a message does not trigger the lambda function. Although I can get message from the topic.